# copying every nth line and duplicating it on it's following line

Tags: matlab

I am trying to make test files for the project, and I figured in order to make a bradycardia test file from an example file of a normal ECG.

Therefore I would need to copy every third line and insert it into the next line.

for example:

```
a = [
    1
    2
    3
    4
    5
    6
    7
    8
    9
    10]
```

and I want:

```
b = [
    1
    2
    3
    3
    4
    5
    6
    6
    7
    8
    9
    9
    10]
```

and so on... but since the file is 6000 characters long, obviously i cannot manually copy it. And I need it to be 9000 characters long  I've tried looking online on how to do this, and am having no luck.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The first sentence of your question means nothing to me. Is it relevant to the problem? Are the vectors `a` and `b` examples of the data, or are they just examples of how lines of text should repeat?

Answer (score 2):

```
b=zeros(floor(4/3*length(a)),1);
b(1:4:end)=a(1:3:end);
b(2:4:end)=a(2:3:end);
b(3:4:end)=a(3:3:end);
b(4:4:end)=a(3:3:end);
```

Comment: this is great!  one other thing, is that the vector 'a' is a 6000x1

so it looks like this:

a = 
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10

and i want:

b =

1
2
3
3
4
5
6
6
7
8
9
9
10

Comment: Sorry, I have edited my answer, just a change to the initialisation of `b`.

Answer (score 2):

Another way:

```
b = a(sort([1:numel(a) 3:3:numel(a)]))
```

Answer (score 2):

And here is a third faster and simpler method

```
b = a(round(1:0.75:numel(a)))
```

Answer (score 1):

This only works if `length(a)` is a multiple of `3`, but seems to be faster than the other answers, at least for large vectors:

```
b = reshape([reshape(a,3,[]); a(3:3:end).'],[],1);
```